# CloudBlobDirectory' does not contain a definition for 'ListBlobs' and no accessible extension method 'ListBlobs' in .net core 3.1 upgrade

Tags: azure-blob-storage, .net-core-3.1

I am upgrading a .net45 app to .net core 3.1 and I have a piece of code there like below.

```
private void GetContainerDirectories(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList)
        {
            // First list all the actual FILES within
            // the current blob list. No recursion needed:
            foreach (var item in blobList.Where
            ((blobItem, type) => blobItem is CloudBlockBlob))
            {
                var blobFile = item as CloudBlockBlob;
                sb.Add(new Tree { Name = blobFile.Name, Id = blobFile.Name, ParentId = blobFile.Parent.Prefix, Title = Path.GetFileName(blobFile.Name), IsDirectory = false });
            }

            // List all additional subdirectories
            // in the current directory, and call recursively:
            foreach (var item in blobList.Where
            ((blobItem, type) => blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory))
            {
                var directory = item as CloudBlobDirectory;
                sb.Add(new Tree { Name = directory.Prefix, Id = directory.Prefix, ParentId = directory.Parent.Prefix, Title = new DirectoryInfo(directory.Prefix).Name, IsDirectory = true });

                // Call this method recursively to retrieve subdirectories within the current:
                GetContainerDirectories(directory.ListBlobs()); ***////////Here i am getting error***
            }
        }
```

In the last line [ GetContainerDirectories(directory.ListBlobs()) ], I am getting error for ListBlobs and I am not able to find any useful solution for this. The error like this - 
*'CloudBlobDirectory' does not contain a definition for 'ListBlobs' and no accessible extension method 'ListBlobs' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlobDirectory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Has anyone any idea how to fix this ? Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What version of SDK you're using?

Comment: I  am using WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.0.0" and the application's target framework is netcoreapp 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WindowsAzure.Storage` SDK you are using is too old, `.net core` does not support the synchronous methods under this SDK, and the `ListBlobs` method is a synchronous method.

I suggest you use the latest SDK instead:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.8.0

If you don't want to use `Azure.Storage.Blobs` SDK, you can use [ListBlobsSegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) method under `WindowsAzure.Storage` SDK

---

**Update:**

You can use the code below to instead of your original code:

```
    var blobs = directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100, null, null, null).Result.Results;
    GetContainerDirectories(blobs);
```

Comment: Hi Frank, I see there are some parameters for ListBlobSegmented method. How to use them? can you please give an update/modifixcation to the piece of code that i shared in the question by using this method?

Comment: Here is an update : If I use like  GetContainerDirectories(directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null)); , then it says Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobResultSegment>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem>'. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

public static async Task GetFileListURLBlobS()
{
try
{
// Initialize a BlobServiceClient object
string connectionString = "Enter your connection string";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

```
            // Get a reference to the container
            string containerName = "Enter Continer Name";
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            
            // Retrieve a list of all blobs in the container
            await foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                // Print the name of each blob
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
                string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(blob.Name);
                //.png, .csv,.json,.jpg,.mp4, .wav, .txt that files are not including
                if (extension == ".docx" || extension == ".pdf" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".mp3")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter path to preview" + blob.Name);
                    }
                }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).